# Segmentation Fault when trying to increment letters

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc > 2){ printf("too many arguments\n"); return 51; }
    if(argc < 2){ printf("too few arguments\n"); return 50; }
    if(strlen(argv[1]) > 4){ printf("Password is greater than 4 characters\n"); return 52; }

    if(argc == 2) //make sure there are enough args
    {
        string hash_guess = "A";

        while(crypt(hash_guess, "50") != argv[1]) //while answer not correct
        {
            while(hash_guess[0] <= 'Z' && hash_guess[0] >= 'A')
            {
                hash_guess[0] = hash_guess[0] + 1;
                printf("%s", hash_guess);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to increment letter by letter through a word, so it would go a then b then c until z then it will go aa, ab, ac, ad.... then ba bb bc bd... then za... zz... zzz. I'm starting with one letter, but I get error "segmentation fault"

Comment: There is no C type called `string`.  Use `char hash_guess[] = "A"`

Comment: Id' help if we had the crypt() function.  Also, `string` is not a C type.  Is this C or C++?  If so, what is `string`?

Comment: One more thing, there is no need for `if(argc == 2)`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - not `c` or `c++` but `cs50`

Comment: Ignoring the rest of the code why does something like this make a segmentation fault:

string[x]++;

Comment: @KevinDTimm - Regarding your edit, I did not want to revert before checking with you first,...  `cs50` falls within the bounds of `C`, so I believe the C tag can still apply.  i.e., stated in the tag's description: _...This tag should be used for questions which use the cs50.h header or cs50 library along with the C tag._

Comment: Depending on what type `string` is, that increment could be undefined behavior.  Imagine if it were in ROM and you told it to write back an incremented address.

Comment: @ryker - IMNSHO, it's not `c` when it uses the `cs50` string type - so many troubles come from that one particular `enhancement` (as you found in your answer)

Comment: Since you are studying through the horrible cs50 tutorial, you will learn incorrect use of C strings from the start. This is the source of your bug. Throw cs50 out the window and get a good book instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised you are getting a seg-fault.  The code you are showing should not even compile.

The line:

```
   string hash_guess = "A";
```

uses `string` as a type.  Unless you have typedef'd `string` in a part of your code somewhere not shown, it cannot be used to create a variable.

Try:

```
   char hash_guess[] = "A";//creates array of char, 2 bytes long:  |A|0|
```

Even then, if you need this variable to contain more than just 2 bytes, create it with more space:

```
   char hash_guess[10] = "A"; Creates space for 10 bytes: |A|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

Remember that a C string is defined as an array of char terminated with a NULL.

*EDIT*  Per @MichaelDorgan's finding, `cs50` typedefs `String` as `char *`.  So the offending line now becomes equivalent to:

```
   char *hash_guess = "A";
```

Which is why it compiles and runs.   The segfault could be happening when you explicitly attempt to write to a location in memory that you do not own, which is *[UB](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs)*.  (however, it is not clear from looking at your code that this is what is happening, just a guess)

Another conventional way to create and initialize a pointer, then create space (for more than two bytes):

```
String hash_guess = {0};
hash_guess = calloc(10, 1);
if(hash_guess)
{
    //... (your code here)
    //hash_guess can now contain up to 9 characters and the NULL terminator.
}
free(hash_guess);
```

Comment: The problem is, we just don't know what `string` is.  Is it a naked pointer?  Perhaps const value to a ROM table?  Or maybe even just a `char` that his special system knows to auto terminate.  This falls under need more info I believe.

Comment: Yup, that's what I needed to do. a char array works.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - At the very least we know that within the bounds of what is shown, `string` should not be able to create a variable as it is not a type.

Comment: Looked it up - string in cs50 is typedef to char*.  So now we know.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - good find.  That changes things a little.  It is not evident in the shown code, but if at any point more than two bytes are assigned to `hash_guess`, then a `seg-fault` becomes a possibility.

Comment: cs50 is an crap library that defines `string` as `char*`. Using this crap library/tutorial is the source of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the reason for the segfault, just for information, is that you are using compiler's read only memory as temporary storage.

```
typedef string char*;

string hash_guess = "A";
```

The compiler generates a 2 entry constant memory array of 'A' and '\0'.  You cannot write to this memory.  It is Undefined Behavior.  (UB)

```
        while(hash_guess[0] <= 'Z' && hash_guess[0] >= 'A')
        {
            hash_guess[0] = hash_guess[0] + 1;
```

...

Is illegal.  You need a temp char array to hold your guess for this to be legal.

```
char my_guess[5];  // You specify a max length of 4.  Make a constant soon please.
strcpy(my_guess, hash_guess);  // Real code never uses this function for safety reasons.

// Beware that later when going to multi-letter check, you will 
// need to re- NUL terminate the string...

        while(my_guess[0] <= 'Z' && my_guess[0] >= 'A')
        {
            my_guess[0] = my_guess[0] + 1;
// ...
```

`my_guess`is on the stack and safely usable.